# Upload Asset object to Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a list of images stored as assets:

```
List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
```

Previously I stored images as files. I could upload them to Firebase like this:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
```

How can I do this but with `Asset`?

Comment: Copy the asset to a temporary file.

Comment: Thank you, this should work